# how to handle exceptions in ejb 3 based soap webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish, ejb-3.0

I am currently developing an EJB3 based SOAP webservice and I wonder what are the best practices to handles uncatched exceptions and return a well formated SOAP response to the client.

example:

```
@WebMethod
public SomeResponse processSomeService(
        @WebParam(name = "someParameters") SomeParameters someParameters)
{
     // the EJB do something with the parameters
     // and retrieve a response fot the client
     SomeResponse theResponse = this.doSomething(someParameters);

     return theResponse;
}
```

Do I have to catch generic exception like:

```
@WebMethod
public SomeResponse processSomeService(
        @WebParam(name = "someParameters") SomeParameters someParameters)
{
     // the EJB do something with the parameters
     // and retrieve a response to return to the client
     try
     {
         SomeResponse theResponse = this.doSomething(someParameters);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         // log the exception
         logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "something is going wrong {0}", ex.getMessage());
         // get a generic error response not to let the
         // technical reason going to the client
         SomeResponse theResponse = SomeResponse.createError();
     }

     return theResponse;
}
```

Is there some kind of "best practice" in order to achieve this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return a SOAP message in the event of an error, you'll have to create it.  I wouldn't expect a container to know what you need.

I would say that your design is adequate.  The one criticism I'd have is that you can't be specific about the nature of the error.

Comment: The idea is to return a generic error message like "server overload", not to let the real error going through the client. thanks for your response

Comment: @Alexandre: You can hide the meaning of the real error by returning an error code to the client. This can be helpful in resolving problems later down the line.

Comment: I finally catch the generic exception and add an error code depending on the exception type. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not good practice to return the error in the response, SOAP defines a SOAP fault for handling the return of errors. As was pointed out by Michael Konietzka, the container can handle the exception thrown and convert it to a SOAP fault.

In your case though, it seems you would like to catch and log the exception first - throw a new EJBException wrapping the original exception.

Answer (score 0):

No need to catch them, the ejb-container will handle this.

**UPDATE regarding the comment #1 by Alexandre GUIDET**

From the EJB 3.1 specification, Chapter 14.2.2 Exception Handling -> System Exception:

- *If the bean method encounters a
  system exception or error, it should
  simply propagate the error from the
  bean method to the container (i.e.,
  the bean method does not have to
  catch the exception).*
- *If the bean method performs an
  operation that results in a checked
  exception that the bean method cannot
  recover, the bean method should throw
  the javax.ejb.EJBException that wraps
  the original exception.*
- *Any other unexpected error conditions
  should be reported using the
  javax.ejb.EJBException.*

So propagating the RuntimeException to the container is the way the EJB specification recommends.

Comment: unfortunately, it seems that some exceptions are not catched by the ejb-container and are returned via a SOAP response to the client

Comment: @Alexandre: Yes, of course. That is what the container is supposed to do, returning the runtime exception as a SOAPFault.

Comment: @Alexandre To be fair, I reset the votes to 0: I guess your question is not about ejb 3.0 web services in particular, but about best practices in developing web services in general...